# Persistence mode for Intel Xeon Phi OpenCL

Tags: opencl, nvidia, xeon-phi

Having a Tesla K20m, the `nvidia-smi` allows to set `persistence mode`, reducing the initialization time of OpenCL (the first steps) and reducing the memory consumption (or at least without memory leaks in the system after the program finishes).

Does the Intel Xeon Phi has something like this?

In case it does not have it, any way to reduce the initialization times of the driver?

**Edit: Persistence mode**: The nvidia-persistenced utility is used to enable persistent software state in the NVIDIA driver.  When persistence mode is enabled, the daemon prevents the driver from releasing device state when the device is not in use.  This can improve the startup time of new clients in this scenario.

Comment: Did you check offline-online compiling of opencl?
 https://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/online-offline-compilation/

Comment: Yes, but this is not persistence mode. Check: http://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/driver-persistence/index.html